# jQuery get diff between two objects with arrays of objects

Tags: jquery, object, hash, diff

Pulling my hair out over this one,

I am trying to get the diff between two objects like this. They are nested objects not arrays:

```
Object a { innerA={...}, innerB={..}, innerC={...} }
Object b { innerA={...}, innerC={...} }
```

The difference should be innerB object.

I have use of the jQuery lib (1.7.2).

I would post code but I have tried so much I wouldn't know what to put anymore!

Comment: jQuery doesn't have anything that will help you here, you'll have to loop through them yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var a = { innerA:{}, innerB:{}, innerC:{} };
var b = { innerA:{}, innerC:{} };

$.each(a, function(index){
    if(!b[index]) {
        // do what you want
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8Tyn/)

Comment: Thanks, so simple in the end I was over complicating it!